# SQL (local) does not work

Tags: c#, sql-server

I've got a problem with fresh install of SQL Server.

ConnectinString:

```
Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=SGGW.USS;Integrated Security=SSPI;Pooling=false
```

but this works

```
Data Source=.\EOGSQL;Initial Catalog=SGGW.USS;Integrated Security=SSPI;Pooling=false
```

EOGSQL is my local machine only running SqlServer Database

EOG

Comment: Shouldn't it be "Data Source=localhost" ?

Comment: which version of sql server did you installed?

Comment: You might want to tell us what the actual problem is.

Comment: you should use Data Source=. or (localhost)

Comment: @all `Data Source=(local)` should work. see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2008/09/19/understanding-data-source-local-in-sql-server-connection-strings.aspx

Comment: @Bala as people suggested, the issue is that he is using a named instance, not the fact that (local) shouldn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a Named Instance, so the connection string must be MachineName\InstanceName, or ip instead of machine name for that matter.

Answer (score 4):

(local) is actually a keyword and not a specific reference to the local machine (although it seems that way sometimes by how it is used).  Here is more information about what it really means:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2008/09/19/understanding-data-source-local-in-sql-server-connection-strings.aspx

In your case, the issue is that (local) refers to the machine and default instance while `.\EOGSQL` refers to an instance on your local machine (local machine is designated by the period).  Basically, this is working as intended.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you have installed SQL SERVER on a named instance instead of using the default instance ( local or .)

Hope this helps